# In React why don't people pass props/state directly to children but create a temporary const variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For example, why not use `value={this.props.temperature}` in the example below? state has a similar usage.

Is this just to be functional, so that the underlying components cannot modify the state of the upper layer? Is it a restriction or a convention?

```js
render() {
    const temperature = this.props.temperature;
    const scale = this.props.scale;
    return (
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Enter temperature in {scaleNames[scale]}:</legend>
        <input value={temperature}
               onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </fieldset>
    );
  }
```

Comment: It has no functional impact, but it does arguably make it more comprehensible to show all the values being used from props in one place, rather than scattering access throughout the JSX. FWIW I'd prefer destructuring, `const { scale, temperature } = this.props;`.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a syntactic sugar to use a **const** here instead of the long form `this.props.something`, It also gives you the ability to edit it in one place, instead of editing it in every place (e.g changing the name of the prop)